# Need help! installed a virus need to uninstall it!

Tags: translation

[image: Probably a virus]

I need to uninstall a virus but this message keeps popping up. I can't uninstall it until I guess correctly what it is. I am assuming it is Chinese as Google Translate picked up the first word 'fun'. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 乐逗边蛀 random misaligned sequence of characters with wavy line, user required to type in as security measure?

Answer (score 1):

Why did you install a virus? Strange thing to do!

Must be a captcha. It says 乐 逗 边 蛀 lè dòu biān zhù so now you need Chinese input.

When you enter it, your computer will be permanently, irretrievably linked to the Department of Homeland Security in Washington！ Have fun with that!

Comment: I didn't get this part about the Washington security. What do you mean?

Comment: It is just a joke.

Comment: I actually meant to remove the activate Windows 10 sign. I thought it would do that. I did not know it would be a virus.